# How to have rotated Ellipse shape in Java?

Tags: java, awt, ellipse

How to have rotated ellipse Shape in java? I.e. so that its semi-axes are not parallel to coordinate axes?

P.S. I need not just draw this ellipse but have it in memory as a shape object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just take an `Ellipse2D` object and apply an `AffineTransform` rotation to it, no?

```
AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI / 4)
  .createTransformedShape(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 2, 1));
```