# How do I set the position of a GeneralPath in a JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, java-2d

I have to do an exercise where is required to put a black `JPanel` on the left where I have to draw a *star-shaped* `GeneralPath` and some buttons on the right that will have to move that general path, plus a reset button that will set the position of the general path in the middle of the panel.

This is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class SunGUI extends JFrame {
    private Space space;
    private Control control;
    private final int DELTA = 50;
    private int posX, posY;

    public SunGUI() {
        Container cnt = getContentPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        space = new Space();
        control = new Control();

        cnt.add(space, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cnt.add(control, BorderLayout.EAST);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public class Space extends JPanel {
        private GeneralPath sun;

        public Space() {
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
            sun = createSun();

        }

        public GeneralPath createSun() {
            GeneralPath sun = new GeneralPath();

            sun.moveTo(-30, -30);
            sun.lineTo(50, 50);
            sun.moveTo(50, -30);
            sun.lineTo(-30, 50);
            sun.moveTo(10, -35);
            sun.lineTo(10, 55);
            sun.moveTo(-35, 10);
            sun.lineTo(55, 10);
            sun.moveTo(-5, -25);
            sun.lineTo(25, 45);
            sun.moveTo(25, -25);
            sun.lineTo(-5, 45);
            sun.moveTo(-25, -5);
            sun.lineTo(45, 25);
            sun.moveTo(45, -5);
            sun.lineTo(-25, 25);

            sun.closePath();
            return sun;

        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;

            setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
            setBackground(Color.black);

            g2.setPaint(Color.white);
            g2.draw(sun);

        }
    }

    public class Control extends JPanel {
        private JButton up, down, left, right, reset;
        private JPanel arrows, panel, resetPanel, container;

        public Control() {
            setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

            panel = new JPanel();
            arrows = new JPanel();
            resetPanel = new JPanel();
            container = new JPanel();

            arrows.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4));
            resetPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
            container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));

            up = new JButton("^");
            down = new JButton("v");
            left = new JButton("<");
            right = new JButton(">");
            reset = new JButton("R");

            arrows.add(up);
            arrows.add(left);
            arrows.add(right);
            arrows.add(down);

            resetPanel.add(reset);

            container.add(arrows);
            container.add(resetPanel);
            arrows.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 20));
            resetPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 20));

            panel.add(container);
            panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("Comandi"));
            add(panel);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new SunGUI();

    }
}
```

Right now this code will only show a static GUI with the *star-shaped* general path in the top-left corner, but what I want to do is to put it in the middle of the black panel.

I've searched around the web but I found nothing, does anybody has an idea?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson I used your code, but in this way all the content of the JPanel (included the border) now is translated... How can I move just the GeneralPath? Thank you again.

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle tutorial docs on transforming (i.e. - translating) a shape. You'll learn a ton and get a much better understanding of the answers below - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/transforming.html

Answer (score 1):

```
super.paintComponent(g);
AffineTransform move = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);
g.setTransform(move);
// draw the shape...
```

Comment: Alternately use [`g2.translate(x,y);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#translate-double-double-)..

Answer (score 1):

You can either translate the whole graphics context with g2.translate, as answered by Andrew Thompson (and then reset the transform), or translate only the shape using the [createTransformedShape](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape-java.awt.Shape-) method of AffineTransform. Here is an example: [How to have rotated Ellipse shape in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872311/how-to-have-rotated-ellipse-shape-in-java)